# Trying to load a JDBC driver jar inside plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I can load the classes of a JDBC jar file like this:

```
ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{jarFile.toURI().toURL()}, this.getClass().getClassLoader());

Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver", true, cl);
```

and on inspection of the classloader, I can see a couple of classes, including
the driver class.
But then, when I try to open a connection, I get a "no suitable driver found" error.
What am I missing?

Comment: Eclipse plug-in class loaders won't look at an additional URLClassLoader when looking up classes. They only look at the information in the plug-in's MANIFEST.MF

Comment: Does this mean, dynamic loading at runtime is not possible at all?
Many hints I read pointed to using this.getClass().getClassLoader() as 
parent classloader should work.

Comment: Eclipse/OSGi class loaders are different from ordinary Java class loaders, dynamic jar loading is difficult unless the jar is an OSGi Bundle/Eclipse plugin. If this is always the same Jar you can just add the Jar to the plug-in's `Bundle-ClassPath` in the MANIFEST.MF and there is no need to use a class loader.